# Linkpoint 360 and Person Accounts sync in Lotus Notes

Tags: integration

As of Salesforce documentation link http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=lotus_person_accounts.htm&language=en_US

We now cannot have Connect for Lotus Notes for organizations created after October 2011. Our organization is using Lotus Notes and its a new org created in late 2012. Thus, we cannot have Connect for Lotus Notes for Lotus Notes Integration with Salesforce.

The organization is now looking for using Third Party tool like Linkpoint 360 for integration with Lotus Notes. Can someone who has already implemented Linkpoint 360 for Lotus Notes integration help me with points on Pros and Cons of the same? Is Linkpoint 360 the best answer to integrating Lotus Notes with Salesforce?

I tried to explore more in Google but did not get suitable information for same.

Answer (score 1):

This may be old information, but I had a client who, a little over a year ago, determined that Linkpoint 360 was the *only* alternative in Salesforce to using Connect for Lotus Notes. I recall it perhaps having a few features Connect didn't have, but the "pros" were basically "it is still supported by the vendor and available for install, unlike Connect" and the "cons" were "it's more expensive than Connect".

Comment: Thanks for the information. ""cons" were "it's more expensive than Connect". -> If I am not wrong, Connect used to come inbuilt in Salesforce earlier, so can you clarify the expense factor please?

Comment: Yeah should have said "more expensive than free" :)